# Create QR Codes in Python on a Telit GE-865 Module

Tags: python, embedded, qr-code

I'm trying to create a means to display QR codes on a small display using a Telit GE-865 as the main controller. In short, the Telit would receive an sms and spin that string out to a display in the form of a QR code. I've found a few different python QR code library's (most from the fukuchi ports), but I'm not exactly sure if they can be imported into a Telit module. If anyone has any experience running python on the Telit modules I'd love to hear your experience and get your thoughts on whether this is feasible or not.

Thanks in advance!

Yes, sorry. Forgot to elaborate a bit. My specific concern is that the scripts Telit provides for examples reference a 1 version of Python. Everything in the QR Encoding library that I've been finding usually require 2.6 or later. I'm not sure if the Telit module can handle a QR encoding script or not with it's PIL library. I'm really just trying to wrap my head around it all before I start figuring out how to actually load the libraries onto the module. I also found this site that seems to have a decent amount of info on this topic. link –  user1667373

Comment: Python is Python. Do you have any *specific* concerns?

Comment: Yes, sorry. Forgot to elaborate a bit. My specific concern is that the scripts Telit provides for examples reference a 1 version of Python. Everything in the QR Encoding library that I've been finding usually require 2.6 or later. I'm not sure if the Telit module can handle a QR encoding script or not with it's PIL library. I'm really just trying to wrap my head around it all before I start figuring out how to actually load the libraries onto the module. I also found this site that seems to have a decent amount of info on this topic.
[link](http://wiki.groundlab.cc/doku.php?id=telit_python)

Comment: @user1667373, could you put your comments in your question ?

Answer (score 1):

This device uses a customized version of Python 1.5.2. You may need to back-port whatever library to are using to work with this older version of Python.  Note also that not all standard Python modules are available, and floating point math is not supported.

See section 5 of the "Telit Easy Script in Python" manual for details of what is and is not included. You can find it here: http://www.telit.com/en/products/gsm-gprs.php?p_id=12&p_ac=show&p=47